# suitable regex expr for multiple matches in a logfile to create an alert

Tags: regex, regex-group

I have a log from which i need to be able to generate an alert if 5 or more non-200 http error codes show up consecutively. For example if i get two 499 codes, two 501s, one 404 one after the other(on multiple single lines in the log) i need the expression to look through those lines, determine that code has popped at least 5 times and provide that result.

The match expression that i have now seems to find something that is non-200 but i think because of the way it is written the tool will alert if there is only 499 error code in the log.Here is the expression:
/(bacsvcs/).*?([013-9]{1}\d{2}|2[1-9][1-9]|2\d[1-9]|2[1-9]\d) \d{1}/

Here is a sample log...it may be easier to view if you copy/paste to notepad.

```
10.170.32.12 - - [20/Oct/2019:05:32:57 -0500] "POST /bacsvcs/pridemarkLookupService HTTP/1.1" 200 171096 "-" "-" "35.182.104.198""BACRequestId = New Relic Monitor""APIMGER_Server = 10.170.42.177:8280""RESPOSE_TIME = 0.277" "."
```

10.170.32.12 - - [21/Oct/2019:05:32:58 -0500] "POST /bacsvcs/historySummaryService HTTP/1.1" 200 663 "-" "Order Checks/Bank of America" "171.159.192.10""BACRequestId = GdUbL6dGrkwABHxVApgAAAFD""APIMGER_Server = 10.170.42.178:8280""RESPOSE_TIME = 0.085" "."
10.170.32.12 - - [20/Oct/2019:05:32:57 -0500] "POST /bacsvcs/pridemarkLookupService HTTP/1.1" 200 171096 "-" "-" "35.182.104.198""BACRequestId = New Relic Monitor""APIMGER_Server = 10.170.42.177:8280""RESPOSE_TIME = 0.277" "."
10.170.32.12 - - [21/Oct/2019:05:32:58 -0500] "POST /bacsvcs/historySummaryService HTTP/1.1" 499 663 "-" "Order Checks/Bank of America" "171.159.192.10""BACRequestId = GdUbL6dGrkwABHxVApgAAAFD""APIMGER_Server = 10.170.42.178:8280""RESPOSE_TIME = 0.085" "."
10.170.32.12 - - [20/Oct/2019:05:32:57 -0500] "POST /bacsvcs/pridemarkLookupService HTTP/1.1" 501 171096 "-" "-" "35.182.104.198""BACRequestId = New Relic Monitor""APIMGER_Server = 10.170.42.177:8280""RESPOSE_TIME = 0.277" "."
10.170.32.12 - - [21/Oct/2019:05:32:58 -0500] "POST /bacsvcs/historySummaryService HTTP/1.1" 404 663 "-" "Order Checks/Bank of America" "171.159.192.10""BACRequestId = GdUbL6dGrkwABHxVApgAAAFD""APIMGER_Server = 10.170.42.178:8280""RESPOSE_TIME = 0.085" "."
10.170.32.12 - - [20/Oct/2019:05:32:57 -0500] "POST /bacsvcs/pridemarkLookupService HTTP/1.1" 499 171096 "-" "-" "35.182.104.198""BACRequestId = New Relic Monitor""APIMGER_Server = 10.170.42.177:8280""RESPOSE_TIME = 0.277" "."
10.170.32.12 - - [21/Oct/2019:05:32:58 -0500] "POST /bacsvcs/historySummaryService HTTP/1.1" 501 663 "-" "Order Checks/Bank of America" "171.159.192.10""BACRequestId = GdUbL6dGrkwABHxVApgAAAFD""APIMGER_Server = 10.170.42.178:8280""RESPOSE_TIME = 0.085" "."

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match non 200 codes, you could use `[13-9]\d{2}` to match numbers from 100 till 999 except 200 till 299

I am assuming that the number of spaces are consistent in your logfile. If that is the case, you could use [quantifiers](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html) to repeat a number of times matching non whitepace chars and then whitespace chars to get to the part of the status code and match it.

To match 5 or more times, you could match the first part and repeat that 4 or more times.

```
^(?:\S+\s+){6}/bacsvcs/(?:\S+\s+){2}([13-9]\d{2} \d).*(?:\r?\n(?:\S+\s+){6}/bacsvcs/(?:\S+\s+){2}\1.*){4,}
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:\S+\s+){6}` Repeat 6 times matching 1+ non whitespace chars followed by 1+ whitespace chars
- `/bacsvcs/` Match literally
- `(?:\S+\s+){2}` Repeat 2 times matching 1+ non whitespace chars followed by 1+ whitespace chars
- `([13-9]\d{2} \d)` Capture group 1, match a number 100-999 except 200-299
- `.*` Match 0+ times any char except a newline
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\r?\n` Match a newline
  - `(?:\S+\s+){6}/bacsvcs/(?:\S+\s+){2}\1.*` Match same pattern as before and use a [backreference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) `\1` to refer to the same number captured in the first line
- `){4,}` Close group and repeat 4 or more times

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HXgaOd/1)

Without using a backreference you could use:

```
^(?:\S+\s+){6}/bacsvcs/(?:\S+\s+){2}[13-9]\d{2} \d.*(?:\r?\n(?:\S+\s+){6}/bacsvcs/(?:\S+\s+){2}[13-9]\d{2}.*){4,}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2hrdeE/1)

Comment: thank you so much for the response. I tested your expression and worked as i described but i quickly realized i described it wrong for which i have made an update. so realistically the error codes might come in intermittently behind each other. so i might get three 499 one 501 and one 404. so the expression would need to look for those coming in within the span of five lines in the log.